# Gridshift in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, datum

I try to access to a specific gridshift for a projection but It doesn’t appear in the datum transformation window.

I’m working on QGIS 3.16.16. I want to use the NAD8398.gsb (from NTv2) in a transformation between NAD83 to NAD83 CSRS. If I use the EPSG:4269 to EPSG:8237 (datum), I can use the right transformation (**NAD83 to NAD83(CSRS)v2**). In my case I want to use this specific transformation for a projection between EPSG:32187 and EPSG:2949 or Inverse.

First attempt:

Copy the NAD83-98.gsb in the proj folder and then create a custom projection adding:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-70.5 +k=0.9999 +x_0=304800 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +NAD83-98.gsb +units=m +no_defs
```

Second attempt:

Add a line in Sqlite in grid_transformation (proj.db file) with source EPSG:32187 and target EPSG:2949:

```
INSERT INTO "grid_transformation" VALUES(
'PROJ','EPSG_32187_TO_EPSG_2949','NAD83 to NAD83(CSRS)v2 (1)','Uses NT method which expects longitudes positive west; EPSG GeogCRSs NAD83 (code 4269) and NAD83(CSRS)v2 (code 8237) have longitudes positive east. Can be taken as an approximate transformation NAD83 to WGS 84 – see code1696','EPSG','9615','NTv2','EPSG','32187','EPSG','2949','1.5','EPSG','8656','Latitude and longitude difference file','NAD83-98.gsb',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'SGQ-CAN QC',0);
```

In the end, I only have access to **Inverse of MTM zone7 + Ballpark geographic offset from NAD83 to NAD83(CSRS) + MTM zone7**

Do I miss something, someone can help me?

Comment: Hi, In your first attemp you are not following the documentation. It is written for latest LTR, but I think it was the same in 3.16: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#integrate-an-ntv2-transformation-in-qgis. Remove the `+towgs84` datum transformation from the string and include `+nadgrids=NAD83-98.gsb` as documented. Please @me if that work fine or write an answer.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Sorry for late answer I was on a another project. Yes, it's working, I can access datum's but the datum I need is +proj=noop. Basically what I want a do is take  cartesian data (projection MTM8 here in canada) in NAD83 and do a gridshift and output in the same projection but in NAD83 CSRS. It is possible to do a cartesian to cartesian gridshift?

Comment: Hi, `+proj=noop` is a transformation, and you don't want it, but `+proj=hgridshift +grids=NAD83-98.gsb` transformation instead. And since the grid is defined in geographic coordinates, you cannot perform the grid shift without unprojecting first to a geographic reference system, (perform the horizontal grid shift here) and finally project again to a projected reference system (the same projection from source in your case).